Access Keycloak via node js server
I'm currently in the process of developing a web app, but I have the problem that when the user calls up a certain page, node js(backend) should see all users who are in the client named 'taskflow' and the role 'assembly' load (server side) so that I can then evaluate the data in the server, but the problem is how I can do that.
It would be ideal if I could do it so that I can access all the users who are in the 'taskflow' role via the node js server. I wrote this code for this, but it doesn't work properly. Is there another way to access all users?
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8001/auth/realms/vue-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token', new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: 'taskflow'
    }));

    return response.data.access_token;
}

// Funktion zum Abrufen der Benutzer mit der Rolle „Montage“ von Keycloak
async function getUsersByRole(accessToken) {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8001/auth/admin/realms/vue-realm/users', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        },
        params: {
            'max': 1000 // Maximale Anzahl der zurückgegebenen Benutzer (anpassen nach Bedarf)
        }
    });

    // Filtere Benutzer nach der Rolle „Montage“
    const usersWithRole = response.data.filter(async user => {
        const rolesResponse = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8001/auth/admin/realms/vue-realm/users/${user.id}/role-mappings/realm`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        });

        return rolesResponse.data.some(role => role.name === 'Montage');
    });

    return Promise.all(usersWithRole);
}

// API-Endpunkt zum Abrufen von Benutzern mit der Rolle „Montage“
app.get('/api/worker', authenticate, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
        const users = await getUsersByRole(accessToken);
        res.status(200).json(users);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
});

